# Data is not getting from sqlite DB in device but it is working in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my app I want to display data from sqlite database on UIPicker View.It is working fine in ios simulator but data is not fetched when using iphone device.I m not getting the issue.How it can be solved???

Comment: Remove your application from device and clean your build then re-install that application in your device.

Comment: Please paste your code, so that we could help you

Comment: Just remove app from device and re-built. App should wok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there is sqlite file available at path? sqlite3_open()  will create the file if its not exists. Please check wheather you have created sqlite file in bundle, if yes you cannot do that. The file actually has to already exist and be copied into the bundle as a resource at build time, then used as a template to copy to a writeable area like the documents folder. The best way, if you intend to create a writeable database, would be to get the path to the Documents directory and use that. You can and should do that unconditionally, without regard to whether you are running on the Simulator or not. Indeed, I would suggest not creating any more differences between Simulator behavior and device behavior than you face anyway.